# Playstore Error - You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 4

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

My app **old version is : 2.0.0+4**
and I try to release new update in play store...  **New release version  : 2.0.1+4**

I was right or not? I am still a beginner these..

When I tried to upload play store had these error " **You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 4.** "

Comment: Set version code 2.0.1+5 and build apk.
In your version string Build number is still 4.

Comment: `2.0.0+4 ` is versionName. You need to update your versionCode in order to release a new update to playstore. You should read about app versioning here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flutter project pubspec.yaml
Change version like this

```
version: 2.0.1+5  --> 2.0.1 is version name & 5 is version code
```

When you update the app make sure you update the version code last code +1.

Also, you can change it manually
Gradle file two property (In android project folder)

```
versionCode 5--> make sure increase version code number
versionName '2.0.1'
```

Comment: Shouldn't the build number be "scoped" from within the version number? `1.0.0+1` and `2.0.0+1` are obviously not the same version...

Comment: I have a problem increasing the version name. My current version is 1.2.2. and build 4. I want to release a new version 1.2.3 build 1 . But keep getting an error "Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code.". Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to **increase the version code** number in pubspec.yaml 2.0.1+5.

After that, run **flutter clean** and **build** your app again.